# Group by specific level in a metadata hierarchy

Tags: managed-metadata

Is it possible to group by a specific metadata level in a list, and not jus the lowest selected level?
E.g:
You have the following metadata hierarchy, that you add to the uploaded documents:

- Country 1

  - city 1
  - city 2
  - city 3
- Country 2

  - city 4
  - city 5

I only manage to group documents by the final level in the hierarchy. Is there a solution that allows grouping on a selected level? In this example it would have been really nice to be able to have a view that groups by Country, even though city is selected on a lower level.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you should just have to specify the correct column in the Group By section when creating your view. For example, if your list has a column with the values Country 1, Country 2, Country 3 and then a second column with the values City 1, City 2, City 3, City 4, City 5 then you just need to specify Group By the City column rather than the Country column.

Comment: Yes that would solve it, but than the users would have to select two values instead of one...
My hope was to have just one selection in order to have it as user friendly as possible.